# Show that $|f'(z)|>\frac{n_k}{10k}$ for $1-\frac{1}{n_k}<|z|<1-\frac{1}{2n_k}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{n_k\}$ be a sequence such that $n_k>k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$. Suppose that
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n_k}}{k}.
\end{equation} Show that if $1-\frac{1}{n_k}<|z|<1-\frac{1}{2n_k}$, then
\begin{equation}
|f'(z)|>\frac{n_k}{10k}.
\end{equation} My attempt: By the assumption $k>\frac{1}{k}>\frac{1}{n_k}$, we can show that the radius of convergence of the power series is 1, so we can take term by term differentiation to get
\begin{equation}
f'(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n_kz^{n_k-1}}{k}.
\end{equation} Whst is the next step?

Comment: +1 Interesting question, nicely formatted, reasonable amount of work shown.

Comment: are you sure that there is no gap condition relating $n_{k+1}, n_k$ because as it stands the question looks a bit iffy

Comment: @Conrad, what if we add a condition that $n_k \to \infty$ rapidly.

Comment: that needs to be made precise - the situation I would worry is if say $n_{2k}, n_{2k+1}$ are consecutive but much bigger (think exponentially bigger $n_{2k} >e^{n_{2k-1}}$) then the previous ones and much lower than the higher ones; then the first $2k-1$ terms are negligible because of the $n_{2k}$ in the derivative, the tail is negligible because $z^{n_{2k+2}}$ is then exponentially small in the given range, so only those two terms count; there $z^{n_{2k}}$ is moderate like $1/e$ etc and then the terms that remain are roughly $(z+1)n_{2k}/k$ and the $z+1$ can be as small as $1/n_{2k}$ there

Comment: @Conrad, I am sorry that I don't have any further information about the sequence $\{n_k\}$.