# Existence of the limit of an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, lacunary-series

This is a question related to the problem I asked in  [Show that $|f'(z)|>\frac{n_k}{10k}$ for $1-\frac{1}{n_k}<|z|<1-\frac{1}{2n_k}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846136/show-that-fz-fracn-k10k-for-1-frac1n-kz1-frac12n-k). Suppose that
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z^{n_k}}{k},
\end{equation} where $\{n_k\}$ is a sequence of positive integers with $n_k>e^{n_{k-1}}$ for every $k \ge 2$. Does the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{R \to 1} \int_0^R f'(re^{it}) dr
\end{equation} exist for almost all $t$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$? My idea is that
\begin{equation}
f(re^{it})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n_k r^{n_k-1}}{k}e^{i(n_k-1)t}
\end{equation} implies
\begin{equation}
\int_0^R f'(re^{it}) dr=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n_k}{k} \Big[\int_0^R r^{n_k-1} dr\Big] e^{i(n_k-1)t}=e^{-it}f(Re^{it}),
\end{equation} so it seems that the limit exist $\textit{for all}$ $t$. However, I feel that the question is not so easy. What mistake(s) have I made?

Comment: The question is confusing since you have a $dt$ in one statement,  a $dr$ in your proof etc; this being said, integral of derivative is function itself so not sure why one would ask that - the right question should be the integral of $|f'|$ imho

Comment: @Conrad, thanks for pointing the typos. I have corrected them. It should be $dr$, not $dt$.

Comment: If the question is however as stated (with $dr$ to make sense) note the answer should be $e^{-it}f(Re^{it})$ not what u got

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got a solution. In fact, since $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}<\infty$, $f \in H^2$ and thus the nontangential limits $f^\ast(e^{it})$ exists a.e. on $T$. Hence we are done.